# How to calculate cross border fees for rental cars in the Balkans?

Tags: borders, car-rentals, fees-and-charges, balkans

I'm a Turkish citizen planning a visa-free travel in the Balkan countries and I'm planning to rent a car starting and ending in Skopje, North Macedonia and travelling to Albania, Montenegro, Bosnia and Herzegovina and Serbia.

Several rental car companies, Europcar for example ables you to add €59 Cross Border fee as an extra cost, this says "This option allows you to drive your rental car to selected countries (see T&Cs for the list of authorized countries)." And in the [Terms & Conditions](https://www.europcar.com/files/live/sites/Europcar/files/Conf_email_attachment/CGL_EN_MK.pdf) they include:

```
CROSS BORDER FEE
€ 50,00, *per country per rental*
Allowed to cross the border to every country in mainland Europe, except in Turkey
```

They say this fee is per country per rental, will I pay 50 Euros * 4 countries (€200) or will I pay the €59 fee and it will cover the border crossings?

Comment: Per country, so sounds like you pay for each extra country you enter. That's how I would read it at least.

Comment: The 50€ fee in the T&Cs is, as stated, not including 18% VAT, so if you add VAT, the amount is at least in both cases the same 59€.

Comment: @Leaderboard: that's also what I'm understanding but in the website you can include this fee to order only once.

Answer (score 1):

In 2018, I rented a car from Belgrade airport, and drove through Serbia, Croatia, Slovenia, Italy, Montenegro and Bosnia.

I booked from autoeurope.eu ... and all charges were included. I didn't have to pay anything extra for cross-border movement.

At the border crossings, the officer checked our passports and the car's rental documentation (including insurance). Nothing else.

Do ensure your insurance is valid in all the countries that you are visiting. We were involved in a small incident in Croatia, and had to make an insurance claim.

Comment: Did you not pay anything extra for using the rental car abroad because usage abroad was included in the price, or did you not pay because you kept your trip abroad a secret from the rental company and therefore likely violated your rental conditions? The border officers are not necessarily interested in wether you violate your rental conditions or not, so they letting you through is of no particular significance.

Comment: I did not keep it a secret. The cross-border costs were included in the fee quoted by auto europe. The actual rental was from AVIS, but autoeurope is a good aggregator and is transparent about any charges.